# windowClosed fires more than once. Is this a bug or a feature?

Tags: java, swing, dispose

Take the following code:

```
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class WeirdDialogShitTest implements Runnable {
    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new WeirdDialogShitTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show Dialog") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                showDialog();
            }
        }));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog", Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
        dialog.add(new JLabel("Content here"));
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent event) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "windowClosed fired");
            }
        });
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I expect `windowClosed` to be called once - when the dialog closes.

What actually happens is that it is called twice - once when the dialog closes, and once when the containing frame closes.

When I traced it to see what was going on, here's what I found:

- When `dispose()` is called on the parent, it disposes all children too. Fair enough.
- All child dialogs remain in the list of children despite no longer existing. This seems dodgy to me. (Are they ever removed?)
- `dispose()` unconditionally fires `windowClosed` whether the window is already disposed or not. This seems dodgy to me also.

The end result is getting `windowClosed` once for the dialog itself and once for each ancestor. :/

But maybe this is the intended behaviour?

Comment: "All child dialogs remain in the list of children despite no longer existing. This seems dodgy to me. (Are they ever removed?)". The purpose of dispose is to free up the native resources that the Window and its subcomponents are using. The components still exist in java and can be freely referenced without any exceptions. as per the `dispose()` doc, they can be brought back to identical state with `pack()` or `show()`

Comment: @vandale I realise that, but I would have expected it to be removed form the list of child frames until it's re-validated. If I create 1,000 dialogs and dispose all of them, do all 1,000 of them remain in memory until the application exits? :(

Answer (score 1):

Should use `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` on main frame. This will solve your problem. Try:

```
public class WeirdDialogShitTest implements Runnable {
    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new WeirdDialogShitTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show Dialog") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                showDialog();
            }
        }));
        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Use EXIT_ON_CLOSE here.
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog", Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
        dialog.add(new JLabel("Content here"));
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent event) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "windowClosed fired");

            }
        });
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: We have more than one main window, so EXIT_ON_CLOSE isn't even an option.